# Concepts for realization in applied cryptography

Tags: key-derivation, post-quantum-cryptography, format-preserving, deniable-encryption

I'm a computer science student (not a mathematican) and I'm gonna to write a master degree diploma on applied cryptography. Specifically, I'd like to create a realization of some cryptographic stuff that is not widely deployed or even lacks of realizations by some reason (maybe because it's really new or it's just not very useful in practice for now). I know some concepts that I think meets my situation: [Honey encryption](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Honey_Encryption), Format-preserving encryption, Deniable encryption, Chaffing and winnowing, Key derivation functions (sometimes they lacks of realizations on GPU/FPGA/ASIC), Post-quantum cryptography. Sorry, I can't post more than one link in question due to lack of reputation.

Maybe, I missed some new directions in cryptography today that needs one more realization or even first realization? Please tell me.

Comment: Ideally you'd check this with your supervisor/professors, since he/they will also evaluate the work afterwards. Also, if you find a professor or a PhD student on your campus who needs an implementation, you can discuss your work with this person as it evolves and it can be more fun. Further I think: 1) Don't implement something, if you don't feel comfortable with the maths part of it. 2) It is not necessarily dishonorable to revisit a well known technique with new focus or applied to a different problem than in previous work. So don't look for too exotic.  3) Check with your supervisor! :)